# Property of a monotonically increasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a non-negative differentiable monotonically increasing function in the interval $[0,\infty)$. Assume $f(x)=1$ for all $x>x_b$. Now define the function $$g(x)=xf(x)-\int_0^{x}f(t)dt $$

Also define the function
$$h(x)=\alpha f(x)-g(x)$$
where $\alpha \in(0,\infty)$
. Is it true that $$h(\alpha)\geq h(x)~,~~\forall x \in[0,\infty)$$
If so, what is the intuition behind this result. For instance, note that first part of $g(x)$ is the area of the rectangle with corners at $(0,0)$ and $(x,f(x))$ whereas the second part is the area under the curve $f(t)$ until the point $x$. Thus the difference of former and latter gives the area of the remaining part in the rectangle.

Comment: Considering mfl's answer, what's the condition $f(x)=1,\forall x>x_b$ for ?

Comment: It came from the application I was interested in. This result is essential to prove the existence of a Bayes-Nash Equilibrium in an Myserson auction. In fact, the result which uses this mathematical fact is at times called as Myerson Lemma.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's true. Why? Because $h$ is increasing on $[0,\alpha]$ and decreasing on $[\alpha,\infty)$. Let's check it:

We have that $$g'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)-f(x)=xf'(x).$$ Thus $$h'(x)=\alpha f'(x)-g'(x)=(\alpha-x)f'(x).$$ Since $f'\ge 0$ we have that $h'(x)\ge 0, x<\alpha$ and $h'(x)\le 0, x>\alpha.$ So, we have shown that $\alpha$ is a global maximum and thus we are done.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you for noticing the mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: @mfl it makes sense now. If its not too much to ask, can you give some geometric intuition as well as to what is happening?..  Something similar to what I explained in the last part of the question..